# How do i properly convert the following sql to eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel

I have been on this for a while and it does not seem to yield the same result when i try converting it to laravel eloquent. The code below is the sql version version.

```
select operator_id,flight_type,
count(if(ata <>'' ,ata, NULL)) as flt_arr_count,
count(if(atd <>'' ,atd, NULL)) as flt_dept_count,
count(if(ata <>'' ,ata, NULL)) + count(if(atd <>'' ,atd, NULL)) as Total_Flights ,
sum(if(pob_arr <>'' ,pob_arr, NULL)) as arrival_pob,
sum(if(pob_dept <>'' ,pob_dept, NULL)) as dept_pob,
sum(pob_dept + pob_arr) as Total_POB
from records 
where operator_id = 1
group by operator_id,flight_type
```

and this is the eloquent equivalent i have written

```
Holder::select('operator_id',  'flight_type',
  DB::raw("count(if(ata <>'' ,ata, NULL)) as flt_arr_count"),
  DB::raw("count(if(atd <>'' ,atd, NULL)) as flt_dept_count"),
  DB::raw("count(if(ata <>'' ,ata, NULL)) + count(if(atd <>'' ,atd, NULL)) as Total_Flights"),
  DB::raw("sum(pob_arr) as arrival_pob"),
  DB::raw("sum(pob_dept) as dept_pob"),
  DB::raw("(pob_dept + pob_arr) as Total_POB"))
 ->where('operator_id', 1)
 ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
 ->groupBy(['operator_id', 'flight_type'])
  ->get();
```

Comment: Maybe dumping the query laravel produced would help you in debugging. And just to confirm, table name on `Holder` is `records`, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it had little to do with the eloquent codes, on my view side i was referencing the wrong fields

Answer (score 0):

In your Eloquent query you added `->where('station_id', Request()->station)`. This is not contained in the raw sql.

Comment: i have corrected that, i only did that to test a different criteria, still the returning record remains different from the sql statement, in eloquent, the data is not properly grouped